# Binary matrix entries

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, binary, counting

I have the following problem. I want to create a numpy-matrix of size 2^L x L+2. In the first column are variables, which I define later in the program. In the last L columns should be all possibilities to distribute zeroes and ones (In my opinion binary counting could be an option, see example) In the second column are the number of ones. I need this column to sort the matrix afterwards for the second column.

```
[[ x1, 0,  0,  0,  0]
[ x2, 1, 0,  0,  1]
[ x3, 1, 0,  1,  0]
[ x4, 2, 0,  1,  1]
[ x5, 1, 1,  0,  0]
[ x6, 2, 1,  0,  1]
[ x7, 2, 1,  1,  0]
[ x8, 3, 1,  1,  1]]
```

Comment: Why do you need numpy (matrices) ?

Comment: I think this is not really necessary, because I could transform the matrix after that to a numpy matrix. (I want to use tensor dot later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for seems unlikely to be what you really need in order to solve whatever problem you're having.  That said, it's easy enough to generate the RHS by taking advantage of numpy's broadcasting abilities:

```
>>> L = 3
>>> m = (np.arange(2**L)[:,None] >> np.arange(L)[::-1]) & 1
>>> m
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
>>> np.hstack([m.sum(1,keepdims=True), m])
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 0],
       [3, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

You can insert your column of data in similar fashion.

Comment: You could be right but that said, your solution solved my problem! Thanks :)

Comment: On some systems I have a problem with "keepdims". On my mac with pycharm the program works flawlessly, but on linux the program is not starting. Do u know what could be wrong? (TypeError: 'keep dims' is an invalid keyword argument for this function)

Comment: @HighwayJohn: on the systems where it's not working, you have an outdated version of numpy.

Comment: What is keepsdim actually doing?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of tuples with the content you describe. You can of course change to lists/arrays/matrices/whatever.

```
import itertools
L = []
k = 3
combs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement([0,1], k)
perms = [y for c in combs for y in set(itertools.permutations(c))]
for c in perms:
    L.append(('myvar',sum(c)) + c)
```

Output:

```
In [42]: L
Out[42]:
[('myvar', 0, 0, 0, 0),
 ('myvar', 1, 1, 0, 0),
 ('myvar', 1, 0, 1, 0),
 ('myvar', 1, 0, 0, 1),
 ('myvar', 2, 0, 1, 1),
 ('myvar', 2, 1, 1, 0),
 ('myvar', 2, 1, 0, 1),
 ('myvar', 3, 1, 1, 1)]
```

To sort wrt to a "column" (col 1 in the example), you can use

```
import operator
sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This solutions does not create all possibilities or am I wrong? This is a important point in my problem.

Comment: I think you'd want `product([0,1], repeat=k)` instead of `c_w_r` if you're going the itertools route.

Comment: Right, it was missing the permutations. I edited to make it correct. Or product, indeed.